# ng-class when key in an object

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I want to apply a css class to a button when my product is in cart. I have tried few things like

```
<li class="add-to-cart">
  <button class="btn btn-add-cart" ng-click="cartCtrl.updateCart(product)" 
    ng-class="cartCtrl.cart[product.id] && 'active'">
    <i class="shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</li>
```

and

```
<li class="add-to-cart">
  <button class="btn btn-add-cart" ng-click="cartCtrl.updateCart(product)" 
    ng-class="{active: cartCtrl.cart[product.id]}">
    <i class="shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</li>
```

Snippet of `updateCart` function from my controller:

```
function _updateCart(product) {
    if (ctrl.cart[product.id] == product.quantity) {
      // If a product with same quantity is getting added, remove it from cart
      delete ctrl.cart[product.id];
    } else {
      // add/update into cart
      ctrl.cart[product.id] = product.quantity;
    }
}
```

So `ctrl.cart` has product ids as keys and corresponding quantities as values. `cartCtrl.cart[product.id]` gives quantity if a product id is in cart. And if quantity is more than 0, `active` class should be applied.

But it's not working. It should work because eventually my `expression` should evaluate to a truthly or falsey value. Like `ng-class="{active: 0}"`, `ng-class="{active: 2}"`

Why it's not working?

Comment: what is cartCtrl.cart[product.id]

Comment: show your controller please

Comment: cartCtrl.cart has product as keys and quantity as values

Comment: @Harry Added controller code

Comment: @Hussain, well it should work, I'd suggest you to create a simple demo to reproduces the issue..

Comment: By deleting the item, there is no `0` but `undefined`. If you just need true/false based on the existence of a value in the array you can use double negation by using `!!` in the expression as: `{active: !!cartCtrl.cart[product.id]}`. For better readability I would suggest to create a helper function in your controller that does this, e.g. `cartCtrl.isItemInCart(product.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function _updateCart(product) {
    if (ctrl.cart[product.id] == product.quantity) {
      // If a product with same quantity is getting added, remove it from cart
      var index = ctrl.cart.indexOf(product.id);
      ctrl.cart.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      // add/update into cart
      ctrl.cart[product.product_sku] = product.quantity;
    }
  }
```

From the above code, I have found one issue. You are using `product.product_sku`as index when insert to array. But you are using product id to retrieve. Please use the same in both.

## Answer

I don't know what will the values in the cart object. If you give that, It will be easy to identify.

Try like following

```
ng-class="cartCtrl.cart[product.id]!=null?'active':''"
```

--

```
<li class="add-to-cart">
  <button class="btn btn-add-cart" ng-click="cartCtrl.updateCart(product)" 
    ng-class="cartCtrl.cart[product.id]!=null?'active':''">
    <i class="shopping-cart"></i>
  </button>
</li>
```

Comment: Your solution works but what's wrong with I am doing. I have added code from controller. Please see

Comment: Solution works means, then code works. right? You have done like you are assigned value in ng-class instead of checking the condition. So need to check the condition in ng-class. Don't use jquery to show or hide. In angular, there is default directives to do that. that is ng-if, ng-show, ng-hide.

Comment: There was a typo in my code. Removed it. Have a look.

Comment: I know the directives. I have again updated my question with more explanation.